# AWK print combination of string+bash variable+string

Tags: awk, fasta

I am trying to rename contigs in a fasta file with the isolate ID and numbering contigs from 1 to n using awk.

Fastafile:

```
  >NODE_1_length_172477_cov_46.1343
  GCAGGGCGCAGTTTTTGGAGGCTTGGCAAACCCGTGAGGGAAATTTGGCAGGCAAAATTT
  TGGCGGTCGTGCCGAAAAAAGCGGAGGCGATTTCAAATAAATTGTTTTTCACACATCATC
  CCAAGCGGCAGACGGAGTTTGCAGTCGGACAAATCAGGCAAGGGCGCGCAGAGTAAGTCA
```

The isolate ID is a variable, as I am tying to do this for multiple files. I have come as far as getting it to print isolateIDnumber, but I need >isolateID_number

```
    for file in /dir/*.fasta
    do
        name=$(basename "$file" .fasta)
        awk '/^>/{print "'"$name"'" ++i; next}{print}' $file > rename.fasta
    done;
```

This gives me:

```
 15AR07771
 GCAGGGCGCAGTTTTTGGAGGCTTGGCAAACCCGTGAGGGAAATTTGGCAGGCAAAATTT
 TGGCGGTCGTGCCGAAAAAAGCGGAGGCGATTTCAAATAAATTGTTTTTCACACATCATC
 CCAAGCGGCAGACGGAGTTTGCAGTCGGACAAATCAGGCAAGGGCGCGCAGAGTAAGTCA
```

Desired output:

```
 >15AR0777_1
 GCAGGGCGCAGTTTTTGGAGGCTTGGCAAACCCGTGAGGGAAATTTGGCAGGCAAAATTT
 TGGCGGTCGTGCCGAAAAAAGCGGAGGCGATTTCAAATAAATTGTTTTTCACACATCATC
 CCAAGCGGCAGACGGAGTTTGCAGTCGGACAAATCAGGCAAGGGCGCGCAGAGTAAGTCA
```

Question is, where do I put the string so that it will print >15AR0777_1 instead of 15AR07771

I tried a few variations of the following, but none worked

```
  awk '/^>/{print ">'"$name"'" "_" ++i; next}{print}' $file > rename.fasta
  awk '/^>/{print ">'"$name"'" _++i; next}{print}' $file > rename.fasta
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `awk -v awk_var="$bash_bar"` to transport shell variables into awk scripts. `man awk:`

```
-v var=val
--assign var=val
       Assign the value val to the variable var, before execution of the program begins.  Such variable values are available to the
       BEGIN rule of an AWK program.
```

ie:

```bash
for file in dir/*.fasta
do         
    name=$(basename "$file" .fasta)
    awk -v name="$name" '/^>/{print ">" name "_" ++i; next}{print}' $file > rename.fasta
done
```

Here is an all awk version for it:

```bash
awk '
FNR==1 {                         # new file, close old and make name for new
    close(f)                     # close the old output file
    n=FILENAME                   # get filename of the new file
    gsub(/^.*\/|\.fasta$/,"",n)  # remove path and .fasta
    f="rename_" n ".fasta"       # new output file
}
/^>/ {
    $0=">" n "_" ++i             # >name_number
}
{
    print > f                    # print to output file
}' dir/*.fasta                   # process .fasta files in dir
```

If there is a file `dir/15AR07771.fasta` the script will produce a file `./rename_15AR07771.fasta` of it. (Your version writes all output files to `rename.fasta` and does not even append, you may want to fix that.)

Comment: Thanks for that - it works. 
I know that my code right now overwrites rename.fasta for each file, that was just for testing purposes.

I have a question though, because I had found the -v var=val option in awk and I tried this:

`awk -v var="$name" '/^>/{print var ++i; next}{print}' $file > rename.fasta`

but it didn't produce any output, other than some hidden .nfs000 file

So basically I used the same approach as your version, except I hadn't used ">" and "_".
Do you know why it behaves that way?

Comment: @ch_esr Apparently in `print var ++i` the `++` operator increments `var` (_post-increment_, `var++`), not `i` (_pre-increment_, `++i`). Test:  `awk 'BEGIN{j=2;print i ++j;print i "," j}'`

Comment: Ah I see - that makes sense now! Thanks for your help.